# How do we run *#06# using ADB to get IMEI number?

Tags: applications, adb, imei

I want to run *#06# and display the activity/fragment which shows the IMEI numbers using adb. Kindly help. Details of the fragment and activity as show below:

```
#1: DialpadFragment{27576dd7 #1 id=0x7f0e00b6 dialpad}
    mFragmentId=#7f0e00b6 mContainerId=#7f0e00b6 mTag=dialpad
    mState=5 mIndex=1 mWho=android:fragment:1 mBackStackNesting=0
    mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=true mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
    mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
    mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
    mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{c30ada in DialtactsActivity{104052fa}}
    mActivity=com.android.dialer.DialtactsActivity@104052fa
    mContainer=android.widget.FrameLayout{22c29bbe V.E..... ........ 0,0-720,1230 #7f0e00b6 app:id/dialtacts_container}
    mView=com.android.dialer.dialpad.DialpadFragment$DialpadSlidingRelativeLayout{2c1bbdce V.E..... ........ 0,0-720,1230}
    Child FragmentManager{2efb76c4 in DialpadFragment{27576dd7}}:
      FragmentManager misc state:
        mActivity=com.android.dialer.DialtactsActivity@104052fa
        mContainer=android.app.Fragment$1@3ed979ad
        mParent=DialpadFragment{27576dd7 #1 id=0x7f0e00b6 dialpad}
        mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I can show the IMEI on the given `Activity`/`Fragment` (I don't know if they are responsible for this), but I'm assuming you want to use ADB to display IMEI in user-friendly format, just like you put `*#06#` on the dialpad (compared to [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852106/is-there-an-android-shell-or-adb-command-that-i-could-use-to-get-a-devices-imei))?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I had seen that answer but it doesn't work for me. dumpsys iphonesubinfo doesn't give any output.

Comment: I think you're interested in this as a developer. If that's the case, then why not fetch IMEI from other means and then show the IMEI in a new dialog? This appears to be what native dialer does: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/android-5.1.1_r36/src/com/android/dialer/SpecialCharSequenceMgr.java#301

Comment: Slight change - Interested as a QA. Thanks Firelord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work on all devices/dialers, but it does on mine so it's worth giving it a shot.  From `adb shell`:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.DIAL -d "tel:*%2306%23"
```

See [this chat conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/conversation/imei-dialer-code-from-adb) for more discussion and possibilities.

---

For just getting the number in the shell, you could also try this:

```
$ getprop | grep -i IMEI
[persist.sys.oppo.device.imei]: [<IMEI here>]
```

That's a custom property on my particular device, but yours might have something similar.

Another option **if you have root** (and possibly needing busybox as well):

```
$ su
# service call iphonesubinfo 1 | awk '{ print $NF }' | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' | tr -d '[:space:]' | sed 's/$/\n/'
<IMEI here>
```

One more that is probably device-specific:

```
$ content query --uri content://settings/system --where "name='bd_setting_i'" | sed 's/[^=0-9]*//g' | sed 's/[0-9]*=//g'
<IMEI here>
```

Comment: Thanks Mathew. But I had tried this. Interestingly, it dials the entire *#06# and I don't get the IMEI.

Comment: @ThejusKrishna One last thing to try would be to run the fragment using a similar command to the one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21844594/507761), unfortunately I am not exactly sure what it should be since my device has a custom engineering mode that does not match what you posted.